# Sami API generator - config not passed to theme

Tags: php, api, twig

I'm generating my php app API with Sami: https://github.com/fabpot/sami but I've got a problem with `title` and `favicon` configuration. My config:

```
return new Sami($iterator, array(
    'title'                => 'My title',
    'favicon'              => 'favicon.ico',
    'build_dir'            => __DIR__.'/project/api/build',
    'cache_dir'            => __DIR__.'/project/project/api/cache',
    'default_opened_level' => 2,
));
```

Problem is, that title and favicon is not passed to theme, therefore not generated in html output. The theme:

```
<title>{% block title project.config('title') %}</title>
{% if project.config('favicon') %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ project.config('favicon') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: Now I've read that this problem is reported as an issue on github...